# JS - console.log(..) outputs following the callback function which is inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, callback, codepen

It's a Freecodecamp project (TwitchTV), which displayed several channels data including live stream, onlive, and all. Although I can have expected result (successfully display different channels data), I couldn't understand one issue (since it was not provided satisfied feedback on the community, so I post this question again in stackoverflow). Hopefully it could be answered well.

Here is my code:

```
var usernames = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", 
"storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "MedryBW"];
 var html_all = "";
 var html_live = "";
 var html_offline = "";


$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log("document ready");
 getChannelData();
});


// get JSON data for channels profile 
function getChannelData(i) {
  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++)
    {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
 // url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/twitch/',
 url: 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/' + usernames[i],
 error: function() {
    console.log("error occurred when getting channel data");
 },
  success: function(data) {
   displayData(data); 
  }       
});
}
console.log("hi");
console.log(html_all);
button_click();
//   $(".data").html(html_all); // no data displayed 
}


 /* function: 
 display the channels list
 */
  function displayData(data){
    var logo = "<img src="+data.logo+" target='_blank' />";
    var name = "  <span style='font-size:20px;'>" + data.display_name +"</span>";
    var url = data.url;
    var status = data.status;
    var baseurl = "<a href=" + url + " target='_blank'>" + logo + name;
    html_all += baseurl+"</a>"+"<br>";
    $(".data").html(html_all);

    console.log('test');
    if (status != null) {
    // live list
    html_live += baseurl + "<p>" + status + "</p></a>" +"<br>";
  }
  else {
  // offline list
  html_offline += baseurl + "</a>"  +"<br>";
  }
 }


 /* function:
 add click event to buttons
 */
 function button_click(){
   $("button.button-all").on("click", function() {
   $(".data").html(html_all);
  // console.log(html_all); // test
  });
   $("button.button-live").on("click", function() {
   $(".data").html(html_live);
  });
  $("button.button-offline").on("click", function() {
  $(".data").html(html_offline);
 }); 
}
```

My question: in the defined `getChannelData()` function, after the `for()` loop, the statement `console.log(html_all)` outputs `""`, empty. But the global variable `html_all` is already updated after the `for()` loop, why is empty in here. But then function `button_click()` works as expected. If you open my source code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/juan-coding/pen/NyKGPe?editors=1112), all button works fine. I don't understand, why variable `html_all`'s value can be accessed in `button_click()` function if `html_all` is still empty after `for` loop? Does the callback function `$.ajax({... success: function()` play a role?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that `getChannelData` makes an AJAX call, which is asynchronous. If you put `console.log(html_all)` inside of your `success` callback, you should see what you expect.

Basically, as the document is loaded, your `getChannelData` is called, but the AJAX request takes time to complete; in that time, the document continues to process your script, including the `console.log(html_all)`. The AJAX call is completed and the `html_all` variable is set, so the `button_click()` and everything else will work, just after the `console.log(html_all)` statement has finished.

Comment: If AJAX call is completed until 'button_click()' and 'html_all' is populated with data, then why if put 'console.log(html_all)' after 'button_click()' statement, it stills gives "", empty?

Comment: The order of the `console.log` doesn't matter too much if it's outside of a function; they are effectively processed immediately, when compared to how long the AJAX call can take. You could put the `console.log(html_all)` at the bottom of your file and it would still likely be done before the AJAX call has finished. However, putting it in your AJAX success callback means `console.log(html_all)` won't run until the AJAX call has successfully finished. If you're comfortable with ECMAscript 6 (which is just newer Javascript syntax), there are more ways to deal with **asynchronous** code like this

Comment: Also, someone else mentioned you should indent your code properly; in CodePen, if you go to the arrow at the top of the 'JS' pane (on the far right), you can select the option 'Tidy JS'. This will make your indentations more consistent, which makes it easier for everyone to read!

Comment: I just tried 'Tidy JS'. It works really good. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Until now, after reading through your comments, I have understood that `console.log()` doesn't output data due to the callback function issue. But, as for `button_click()`, is because it is a function which takes longer time than `console.log` to run, so when it runs, `html_all` is updated?

Comment: The `button_click()` function probably doesn't take any longer to execute than the `console.log()`. However, the values `html_all`, `html_live`, and `html_offline` are not accessed until the corresponding button is clicked. The `button_click()` function is just assigning those event listeners to each button, but the event listeners don't do anything until the 'click' event. The data is displayed correctly at first because you call `displayData(data)` inside of your `getChannelData()` success callback.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `ajax` requests are sent asynchronously by default, meaning that the request is sent off and the code does not wait for the response before moving on with the rest of the logic.  When the request eventually comes back, it is evaluated to see if the request was successful and the appropriate code is then run (e.g., `.success(...)`, `.fail(...)`, etc.).

So, what is likely happening here is that all of AJAX requests that are triggered in the `for` loop are sent off, but none of them have received a response yet, by the time that `console.log(html_all);` is reached.  That means that `displayData` has not been called yet, so the the value of `html_all` has not yet been updated and still contains the default empty string value that it was initialized to.